# Net Core IWebHostEnvironment getting only "c:\"

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to move an app from .net to net core 5, and I'm trying to get the content root.

All of the instructions that I see show using IHostingEnvironment in a controller:

However, using this just get's me "c:" and I suspect that it's because I'm trying to use it, not within a Controller, but within the Identity RegisterModel : PageModel in order to grab an html file that will be a source for the confirmation email.

Could that be the problem?

If so, how would I get the path of a file in code that is not in a controller?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to present your .Net Core 5 code to understand the real situation.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code up to the point in question.  The organization of this registration code is different than I'm used to, but it seems like it can't be that hard to just get the root folder so as to refer to a file to read.

Comment: Dangit, that's slightly old code...

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the last state of the code had some other experiments, and my connection timed out and so my undo history got lost.  

I'm thinking that I can just put the relevant path into appsettings.json and move on.

Answer (score 0):

IHostingEnvironment works like a service and needs to be injected in the constructor of the controller. You can use it in your User Controller.

Can't do much considerations without the code to evaluate.

A simple way is: In the constructor of the default controller, set in a static class a member that holds the path for you. Once it's a static class, you can access it from everywhere if you set it to public.