# .Net 6 IWebHostENvironment returns local path on server

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm doing a .Net 6 application and I have a situation where when I deploy to the server, ENV will return a local path and not the server path. It was a hidden bug since it works fine locally.

I found it by surrounding all of the code with a try\catch.

On the server, ENV.ContentRootPath returns
C:\home\site\wwwroot\

That is the path I can see on the server. Why is .Net WebHost returning the local path? I saw another one with the same issue without a resolution. I'm trying to grab an HTML template for an email.
This si the other issue.
[Net Core IWebHostEnvironment getting only "c:\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232399/net-core-iwebhostenvironment-getting-only-c)

Comment: Here is the code.

Comment: I tried to add the codee block bu tit's too long.

Comment: Here is the line that fails.

var loc = Env.ContentRootPath + "/Templates/Notifications/ReceiptEmail.html";
                ViewBag.loc = loc;
                var template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Env.ContentRootPath + "/Templates/Notifications/ReceiptEmail.html");